# python regular expression, how should I find value in parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to search string pattern using regular expression

But since I am very new to regular expression I would like to ask some advice on search pattern

So, I would like to find a line which has 'value' as below
value can be both numbers and alphabets

```
Name (value)
```

I tried to use pattern

```
re.search(r"Name \([a-zA-Z0-9]\)", line)
```

But it doesn't seem to find as I expected.

How should I write search pattern?
Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your expression is fine but your character group lacks a quantifier:

```
re.search(r"Name \([a-zA-Z0-9]+\)", line)
```

The `+` means "at least one of those". If you don't put a quantifier it means only one of the mentioned characters may occur. Possible quantifiers are:

- `+` for one or more,
- `?` for at most one and
- `*` for any number of those
- `{x,y}` works as well, meaning at least `x`, but at most `y` characters

And the quantifier always refers to what you place right before it, which might be a single character or a character group enclosed in `[]`.

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments by *root* you might want to look at `\w`, which is a short notation for "all word characters". It includes all letters and digits, as well as the underscore and maybe special characters if they are specially defined by the current locale.

Comment: +1, but you could also mention that `[a-zA-Z0-9]` could be replaced with `[\w]`

Comment: I guess I could. But there is nothing wrong with specifying exactly what you want, because it makes for more readable regex. And I think `\w` includes more than just letters and digits...there should also be special characters in there according to the locale.

Comment: I agree that there is nothing wrong with `[a-zA-Z0-9]`...it was more meant as "for educative purposes". `\w` also includes an underbar yes... but that's it.